# sqlite3 with python - query debugging - print the final query

Tags: python, debugging, sqlite, profiler

I'm trying to debug a SQL statement generated with `sqlite3` python module...

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE :column = :value" % Photo.DB_TABLE_NAME, {"column": column, "value": value})
```

It is returning no rows when I do a `fetchall()`

When I run this directly on the database

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE album_id = 10
```

I get the expected results.

Is there a way to see the constructed query to see what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is that the string values are automatically embraced with single quotes. You can not dynamically insert column names that way.

Concerning your question, I'm not sure about sqlite3, but in MySQLdb you can get the final query as something like (I am currently not at a computer to check):

```
statement % conn.literal(query_params)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with sqlite: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'literal'

Comment: @RomualdBrunet, you are right. I've took a look at https://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/source/browse/src/ and can not see anything that can be user for the purpose. There is sqlite3.Statement that should have a bind_parameters method, but no methods are available in python for the class.

Answer (score 16):

To actually answer your question, you can use the [`set_trace_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.set_trace_callback) of the connection object to attach the print function; this will make all queries get printed when they are executed. Here is an example in action:

```
# Import and connect to database
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
# This attaches the tracer
conn.set_trace_callback(print)
# Get the cursor, execute some statement as an example
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE stocks (symbol text)")
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?)", t)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print(c.fetchone())
```

This produces the output:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks (symbol text)
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('RHAT')
SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol='RHAT'
('RHAT',)
```

Comment: `conn.set_trace_callback(print)` is the key line here, works with sqlite3 flawlessly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm still getting `INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?)`.

Comment: @feus4177 I concur, in Python 3.10 this seems to not display the concrete values at all, which would be the actually interesting thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use substitution parameters for row values, not column or table names.

Thus, the `:column` in `SELECT * FROM %s WHERE :column = :value` is not allowed.